# Convert XML to Associative array

Tags: php, xml, zend-framework

Is there a way to convert XML to array using Zend Framework and PHP? I have seen folks using SimpleXML to do this, but I wanted to know if there's a way through Zend Framework.

Sample XML, I wanted to convert to array would be:

```
<library>
    <book>
        <authorFirst>Mark</authorFirst>
        <authorLast>Twain</authorLast>
        <title>The Innocents Abroad</title>
    </book>
    <book>
        <authorFirst>Charles</authorFirst>
        <authorLast>Dickens</authorLast>
        <title>Oliver Twist</title>
    </book>
</library>
```

The converted array will look like this:

```
Array 
( 
        [0] => Array ( 
                      [authorFirst] => Mark 
                      [authorLast] => Twain
                      [title] => Innocents Abroad
                     )
        [1] => Array (
                      [authorFirst] => Charles 
                      [authorLast] => Dickens
                      [title] => Oliver Twist
                     )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look aty the [source code](https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/blob/master/library/Zend/Config/Xml.php#L189) of `Zend_Config_XML`, you'll see them using SimpleXML to do almost exactly that. My guess? They'd suggest you do the same.

Answer (score 6):

ZF also uses SimpleXML. For your example:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
$books = array();
foreach ($xml->books as $book) {
    $books[] = (array)$book;
}
```

`var_dump($books)` will then give you:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["authorFirst"]=>
    string(4) "Mark"
    ["authorLast"]=>
    string(5) "Twain"
    ["title"]=>
    string(20) "The Innocents Abroad"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["authorFirst"]=>
    string(7) "Charles"
    ["authorLast"]=>
    string(7) "Dickens"
    ["title"]=>
    string(12) "Oliver Twist"
  }
}
```

if your books may have nested elements then it gets a little more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, or thankfully depending on your point of view, Zend Framework does not have a set of classes for everything possible--as of now. You have to use plain php (like simpleXML or DOMDocument) for this task or implement your own Zend class.

Converting a XML file into a PHP array would be something that fits into Zend_Filter. Zend_Filter converts many things right now and others are under development but I don't see anything like XML [in the queue](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFPROP/Home).